# Open git url of ssh in sourcetree from SourceTree

Tags: javascript, html, git

I want to clone a git url or a git ssh url in sourcetree from a html page.

Bitbucket does it like this:

[image: this is what I want to simulate]

I have searched in the sources but I can't find how you can open something in a Mac/Windows app. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is "the sources"? Please provide more information.

Comment: in the sources of bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long serach I found the answer [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Can-I-make-my-own-quot-Checkout-in-SourceTree-link-quot/qaq-p/69572)

It turns out Sourcetree has a custom url protocol `sourcetree`. You can use this to trigger Sourcetree to open and clone a url.

**Clone Repo:**
`sourcetree://cloneRepo/<CLONE_URL>`

Mac will handle github triggers as well if Github Desktop is not installed:
`github-mac:// URLs`

The release notes (scroll down to 1.4):

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/ReleaseNotes.html

An exampe for javascript:

```
downloadRepo(url){
    const customUrlProtocolSourceTree = "sourcetree://cloneRepo/"
    window.location.href = customUrlProtocolSourceTree + url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future has problems with this, here is what I've found:

To open Sourcetree your have to prepend `sourcetee://cloneRepo` like @Koen Van Looveren said, but then the URL has to look like this:

```
sourcetree://cloneRepo?type=stash&cloneUrl=ssh://git@link.toRepository.com/repositoryName.git
```

Hope it helps somebody who had the same problems!